# Programar tarea en Ubuntu - Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

Que tal soy nuevo en esto de Linux, usando distribución Ubuntu, principalmente quiero programar que a cada cierta hora se ejecute un archivo mp3, no sé si se tenga que realizar con los comandos Cron ó Crontab (no sé si es lo mismo) ó de que manera y cómo puede realizarse, gracias

Comment: Hola Daniel, es difícil saber que necesitas con tan poca info, si es algo tipo "despertador", ahorrate el esfuerzo, baja "Audacious", que es un reproductor en el que puedes programar una hora de ejecución, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Answer (score 0):

`cron` es el programador de tareas de linux. Éste toma sus archivos de configuración de diferentes puntos en el sistema, dependiendo de si son globales o específicos para un usuario. Los archivos de programación de tareas de todo el sistema están en:

1. el archivo `/etc/crontab/`. El archivo `crontab` está compuesto por líneas con el siguiente estilo (tomado del manual):

```
# .---------------- minuto (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hora (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- día del mes (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- mes (1 - 12) o jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- día de la semana (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) o sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * nombre-de-usuario comando
```

Por ejemplo, para ejecutar el comando `echo` diaramente a las 3am como el usuario `root`, se agregaría la siguiente línea:

```
0 3 * * * root echo
```

2. Los directorios `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.monthly` `/etc/cron.weekly`. En estos directorios se pueden colocar ejecutables que deban ejecutarse una vez por día, una vez por hora, una vez por mes, o una vez por semana, respectivamente.
3. El directorio `/etc/cron.d`. En éste se colocan archivos con la misma sintaxis que la del archivo `/etc/crontab`. Esta carpeta existe para facilitar la clasificación y manipulación de tareas individuales.

En el manual se pueden revisar las convenciones para otras combinaciones de horas/días, etc.

Para crear programaciones de cualquiera de estos tres tipos se requiere ser superusuario. Si quieres realizar una programación como un usuario normal, es recomendable utilizar el comando `crontab -e`. Este abrirá un editor de texto, en donde se pueden escribir líneas del estilo del archivo `/etc/crontab`, pero sin la sección de `usuario` (pues siempre se ejecutará como el usuario que lo creó). Tiene la ventaja de que automáticamente busca la ruta del archivo apropiado, y de que, antes de permitir cambios, revisa la sintaxis de cada línea. En la primera ejecución te preguntará qué editor deseas usar (comúnmente será `vim` o `nano`), y es recomendable que sepas cómo hacer una edición básica en estos procesadores.

También debes tomar en cuenta que `cron` no tiene la misma ruta de ejecutables que `bash`. Si ejecutas una tarea en una ruta poco usual, lo más seguro es que incluyas la ruta completa al ejecutable.

Comment: Esta respuesta es muy buena, pero le falta una parte para completar la pregunta. Si explicas cómo ejecutar un audio mp3 con un comando desde cron estará completa. Aún con todo, como la pregunta es muy mala, no se si terminará cerrada o no e igual no vale la pena completar la respuesta.